# Converse of the Perpendicular bisector theorem

Tags: geometry

[image]

For the converse, while I agree that the point will be on the pependicular bisector, we can't assume the line drawn is actually the perpendicular bisector... yet the above textbook example assumes it is. I don't see why, based only on XA=XB, we're allowed to conclude that XY is perpendicular to AB and YA is congruent to YB? Surely to make the given conclusions we'd need to state that if two points are equidistance from the endpoints of a segment, those points determine the perpendicular bisector - what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The conclusion should read:

> There exists a point $Y$ on $AB$ such that $YA\cong YB$ and
> $XY\perp AB$.

Proof.

The first part is obvious, because the existence of midpoint is a theorem (or axiom, depending on how geometry is constructed). Hence $Y$ is the midpoint of $AB$. It remains to show that $XY\perp AB$, and that follows from the congruence of triangles $AXY$ and $BXY$ (by SSS).